I did "sudo gdm3" and now I'm stuck on a black screen
I'm Stuck at a black screen after running "sudo gdm3" at Ubuntu oracular and I'm at a QEMU KVM VNC with Sysrq & Ctrl-Alt-Del disabled
Image of RealVNC On Mobile:


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I think the most straightforward way to fix this is to switch to a TTY (text-only console) session.
If possible, press Ctrl + Alt + F3 (or any function key from F3 to F6,) then log in with your username and password.
If that works, restart the gdm3 service from within the TTY with sudo systemctl restart gdm3.
But if this fails, which it very well migth, try restarting the entire graphical environment with sudo systemctl isolate graphical.target.
And if this still doesn’t work, just reboot the VM from the command line (sudo reboot, if you’re unaware.)

It's a QEMU VM Which Has No Dedicated IPv4 So I Have No SSH Access to it , Ctrl-Alt-Del and Sysrq magic key is disabled and I tried switching to text based console but none of F1 - F9 works for switching to text based and I have no access to physical server running it
